# Trouble getting data out of API using Vue JS

Tags: json, vue.js

I'm having trouble iterating over data from a json file in Vue JS. I've got everything set up and have access to the json. What am I missing here:

**JSON**

```
{
  "test": "example",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "My Name",
      "address": "My Address"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Vue JS html**

```
{{ someData['name'] }}

<ul>
  <li v-for="item in someData" v-bind:key="item.id">
    {{ item }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**and my script:**

```
created() {
    this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/properties.json').then(response => {
      // get body data
      this.someData = response.body
    }, response => {
      // error callback
    });
  }
```

**The result I'm getting is:**

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78rYw.png)

As you can see, in my v-for simply specifying item grabs each of the items here, but I want to be able to do something like {{ item['name'] }} and {{ item['address'] }}

Comment: Please, specify what does `someData` refer to

Comment: Hi, `someData` is just for testing purposes. I've just updated my question above with some new JSON data as I'm having trouble with that part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is in your JSON file. VueJS v-for is iterating over the keys in your JSON file, in this case {{ item }} will be getting name and address. That is the reason of your output.

To solve this...

Format your JSON file as

```
[{name: 'John', address: 'Jane'}]
```

Doing this your VueJS v-for will be iterating over JSON array and {{ item }} will get the value { name: 'John', address: 'Jane' } and now you can do {{ item.name }} {{ item.address }}

An example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/738438/)

EDIT: Update your API request code

```
created() {
    this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/properties.json').then(response => {
      // get body data
      this.someData = [response.body]
    }, response => {
      // error callback
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but my json is going to be coming from an API, or a json file, how would I adapt this?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. it's just occurred to me that my data is going to contain multiples like this:

```
{
  "test": "example",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "My Name",
      "address": "My Address"
    }
  ]
}
```
So now, I tried doing: {{ item.data.name }} and that didn't work?

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: with that JSON modification you must update your created() method to fit what you want. In this case, without viewing the code, I think you will add this.  this.someData = response.body.data.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following:

```
<template v-for="(item, key) in someData">
  <span v-if="key == 'address'">{{item}}</span>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The crucial point is that the `v-for="item in someData"` part in the component's view [iterates over *values*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object) of the `someData` object, namely `"John"` and `"Jane"`.

Depending on what exactly is your goal, you should either reformat the JSON to be an array of objects (as suggested by @F.bernal), or change the logic of `v-for` directive.